# Why do I have no ammo for my pack?

Tags: tribes-ascend

I.e. my soldier has the energy pack, which is supposed to restore a certain amount of energy upon usage.

However, I never have any ammo for the pack, and I don't know how to find it (Not in TDM and neither in CTF). Are some packs disabled for some game modes?

Comment: afaik the energy pack is for your jetpack not ammo for your disc launcher

Comment: I know, that's what I mean anyways

Comment: oh, you are asking if there's an ammo pack you can use instead?

Comment: No, I was under the impression that the pack was something like a short booster for your jetpack. I have since found out that it is instead a permanent bonus. If you want to add that as an answer, I will gladly give you the points :P

Comment: I would recommend utilizing the 'Looter' primary perk. When upgraded to max level it adds a 20% ammo gain + 1 belt item to ammo drops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some packs are passive bonuses that you have all the time. There's no need to activate them! The Soldier pack you're talking about is one of them, where it increases your max energy by 10. There are others, such as the pack that raises your maximum Health, or packs that make it so you start recovering health sooner.

Other packs have to be activated, but the passive packs are always in effect, even if you don't know it!

Comment: If your referring to the Soldier's Utility Pack it offers the following (when fully upgraded): +20 energy, +100 health, +1 belt item, and +10% run speed.

Answer (score 1):

The energy pack is not an active pack, it's a passive one that increases your max energy.

(As a rule of thumb, any packs dealing with energy are passive bonuses, because all of the active packs use energy as their activation cost.)

Comment: The only pack "dealing with energy" is the Energy Pack. It works the same for all classes that utilize it.

Comment: @Nick - incorrect. There are two packs specifically dealing with energy. One is the Soldier/Brute Energy Pack, which increases max energy. The other is the Pathfinder/Sentinel Energy Recharge Pack, which increases energy recharge rate.

Comment: That's my mistake. http://www.tribesascendwiki.com/Energy_Pack http://www.tribesascendwiki.com/Energy_Recharge. And I suppose the Soldier Utility Pack counts as a third type. http://www.tribesascendwiki.com/Utility_Pack